# Terminology: what is the difference between stochastic and aleatory

Tags: terminology

Is there a difference in the meanings of stochastic and aleatory? Are these words interchangeable? So far I have not been able to find a meaningful difference.

Comment: A process can be stochastic...a variable can be random or aleatory.  See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114373/whats-the-difference-between-stochastic-and-random/1226731#1226731) for a related discussion.

Comment: The word aleatory (translation from French "aléatoire" ?) is uncommon in english. "Random" should be used instead.

Comment: Aleatory is a fine word to use in English. It is the term I've always heard used when describing John Cage's chance-based musical works.

Answer (score 1):

Aleatory is a subset  of stochastic. A stochastic process is aleatoric or epistemic. If it is aleatoric, the uncertainty inherently cannot be reduced. If it is epistemic, then cleverly adding data can reduce the uncertainty.