# How can Wiener process be integrated w.r.t. time?

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the RDE $$X_t = \int_0^t e^{cW_s}ds$$
where $c>0$ and $W_t$ is Wiener process.
Can this integral be solved, i.e. can Wiener process be integrated w.r.t. time?

Now consider the integral $$X_t = \int_0^t sin(s)dB_s.$$ This integral cannot be further solved, is this correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72208/whats-the-difference-between-rde-and-sde

Comment: Stochastic differential equations?

Comment: Do you mean $y'(x)=f(x,y(x),p)$ and the parameters $p$ get randomly selected? Or that the coefficients vary randomly in time?

Comment: What do you mean with a "random differntial equation" ? An arbitary equation involving derivates ?

Comment: Assuming that $B$ is also a Brownian motion the integral $\int_0^t\sin(s)\,dB_s$ has nothing to do with the title of your question. It cannot be further solved but it can be related to the integral $\int_0^t B_s\cos s\,ds$. Hint: integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

- The correct way to write this equation is either
  $$
  X_t=\int_0^te^{cW_\color{red}{s}}\,d\color{red}{s}
  $$
  or -in differential form-
  $$
  dX_t=e^{cW_t}\,dt\,.
  $$
  It looks like you mixed up both.
- This integral is well defined even as a Riemann integral because for each $\omega$ the path $t\mapsto W_t(\omega)$ is continuous.
- It cannot be solved like we solve
  $$
  \int_0^te^{cs}\,ds=\frac{e^{ct}-1}{c}\,
  $$
  but this has not stopped generations of mathematicians to work with such integrals
  in the theory of stochastic differential equations or financial mathematics.

For example: Since Black & Scholes it is popular to model a stock price essentially by
$$
S_t=S_0e^{cW_t-c^2t/2}\,.
$$
Then
$$
X_t=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tS_s\,ds
$$
describes the average stock price which is the underlying of an Asian option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **Random** differential equation, which differs from a **Stochastic** differential equations.

An RDE (or RODE) is an (path-wise) ODE containing a random process, in this case a Wiener process.  Because of this, in a path-wise sense, the solution can be handled using standard (deterministic) calculus.

An SDE (driven by standard Brownian motion) is an equation of the form

$$dX_t = f(t,X_t)dt + g(t,X_t)dW_t,\,\, W_t : \text{ Wiener process}$$
Your notation is incorrect, you are mixing differential and integral forms.

$$\frac{dX_t}{dt} = e^{cW_t} \text{ or } X_t = \int_0^t e^{cW_s}ds$$

**An aside**: Interestingly, calling them stochastic *differential* equations is a bit of a misnomer, since sample paths are nowhere differentiable, so really they are stochastic integral equations.

Here is one numerical solution using Julia programming language with initial condition $X_0 = 1.0$ and $c = 2.0$ (cf. [Julia DiffEq](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/tutorials/rode_example/))

[image]

I recommend the following book [Random Ordinary Differential Equations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-10-6265-0)

**EDIT**: OP has added a stochastic integral question below original RDE question, for such integrals I recommend the following book: [Stochastic Differential Equations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-14394-6)

Comment: So how to compute this solution then?

Comment: I said an RDE is an ODE defined path-wise, thus for a given realization, we may solve it using deterministic calculus, i.e. sans probability. The caveat is though this is path-wise, so each realization will be different with a positive probability.